# How to retrieve only font style(Bold,italic,Bold Italic) from font panel(NSFontPanel) and color?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfont, nsfontpanel

I am retrieving a value from `NSFontPanel`, which changes the font family, style of text. But I want only Font Style and color separately that I have selected from `NSFontPanel`.

I am not getting how to get that.

```
NSFont *font  =[fontmanager selectedFont];
     string =[font fontName];
     st = [font pointSize];
    color =[TextEntered textColor];
```

1. In string variable I am getting Font family(e.g.Arial) and Font style(e.g. Bold). but I want these values separately.
2. And in color variable I only get black color.

I am not able to understand where I am wrong in getting color,and what function I used for getting font style..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the style, you would use `[fontmanager traitsOfFont: font]`.  As for the color, I think you want to get the text as an `NSAttributedString` and then get the value for the attribute `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Edit to add: Assuming that your TextEntered variable is NSTextField*, use something like this:

```
NSAttributedString* theText = [TextEntered attributedStringValue];
NSColor* theColor = (NSColor*)[theText attribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
    atIndex: 0 effectiveRange: NULL ];
```

For strikethrough, use `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` and for underline use `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`.

Comment: example of getting color. and thanks for answering..it works for getting font style.

Comment: and will you plz also tell me how to get strike through and underline from NSFontPanel.